# In Google Web Apps how to split the javascript into several file?

Tags: google-apps-script

In a Google Web App I try to split my js code into several file.
To begin, I move my script in a JavaScript.html file. This file being like this

```
<script>
  console.log('script loaded')
</script>
```

As advised in the Google documentation, my code.gs contains this

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
....
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename).getContent();
}
```

and my index.html ends like this

```
        <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

It appears that the include line is not interpreted correctly and is displayed as is.
What is wrong

Answer (score 2):

Reading more carefully the doc I found my mistake.

Changed doGet method with

```
function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate()
}
```

It works now !